# ifplatform.sty error after installing MiKTeX on Ubuntu Mate 16.04

Tags: minted, ubuntu, linux, ifplatform

I can't tell if this is Windows or *nix; you appear to be neither.

The error above is what I receive even when I try to compile something as simple as this:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article} 
\usepackage{minted}

\begin{document}
    Test Text
\end{document}
```

The error is clearly caused by the `minted` package being included (I assume it requires `ifplatform`) because the documents that don't use the `minted` package compile fine. I've tried compiling using both pdfTeX and XeTeX (with the `-shell-escape` argument of course.)

This error never popped up in the past when I had some distribution of LaTeX that got installed automatically when I installed TeXmaker through apt. But I installed MiKTeX because it's a lot easier to get new packages with it. That's when this problem started.

I tried reading the documentation for `ifplatform` and it said something about things becoming confused if there's a `nul:.tex` file in the search path. I only found a `null.tex` but deleted it anyway and it didn't help.

I'd really appreciate any help regarding the matter, thanks in advance!

EDIT: The point I mentioned about the documentation is on page 3 of the documentation found [here](http://mirror.hmc.edu/ctan/macros/latex/contrib/ifplatform/ifplatform.pdf).

Comment: I don't see anything in the style that looks as if something miktex specific could confuse it but as I'm on windows I can't test. Make a copy of the style in a test folder and then try to find out which way the tests go by add \show\x in sensible places while running your document (better don't use minted but only ifplatform for this tests).

Comment: can you reproduce with just ifplatform (and not minted)

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I get the same error however the document compiles successfully if I include ifplatform instead of minted.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer I don't quite understand what you mean by " make a copy of the style" or what you want me to try doing in general actually.

Comment: copy ifplatform.sty to your actual folder. It will then be used by your document and you can change it without breaking the original. Then open this copy in your editor and try to figure out what it is doing by adding debugging messages (I often use simply \show\x to understand where I am).

Comment: I do not understand "I get the same error" and "document compiles successfully" they can not both be true? If you get the error without using minted that makes it _much_ easier to debug as minted is a big complicated package with multiple dependencies.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Sorry for the ambiguity, it still shows the same message "I can't tell if this is Windows or *nix; you appear to be neither.", but this time it's not exactly an error but a warning, so the document compiles fine.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer I see, so what you mean is to add the line \show\x at arbitrary points in ifplatform.sty and try to find out at what point the error occurs?

Comment: Yes but the problem is not much to find the point of the error but finding the point where the logic goes wrong.

Comment: I don't know if this is the case, but I've a [issue](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/517339/miktex-re-downloading-iftex#comment1308331_517339) recently when I update my MikTeX distibution.

Answer (score 0):

This works for me and makes the `.tex` file compiles with no problem (I am using a Mac with MiKTeX and texMaker and had the same problem):

```
\ProvidesFile{ifplatform.sty}
\newif\ifwindows\windowsfalse
\usepackage{minted}
```