# Miktex re-downloading iftex

Tags: packages, miktex, miktex2.9

Using MikTex 2.9.7206 on Windows

I have already (manually, sucessfully) installed the package `iftex`.

Every time I try to compile a document which uses parts of the package, it tries to download and install the package but fails.
After that the package is not listed as installed in the package-manager anymore.

Just skipping the installation (or disabling on-the-fly installation) will create a successfully compiled document.

Does anyone know how to fix this problem?

Comment: Go to the miktex console and then update the package database (in the package section click on the icon). Do this at best in user and admin mode. And then install the package through the package manager.

Comment: Anyway, you should update: present version is 7262.

Comment: There is the same issue here : https://github.com/MiKTeX/miktex-packaging/issues/140 andI had the same problem. As for me, I was forced to reinstall MikTeX and this solved the problem.

Comment: The solution was to update the package-database also in user-mode and not only in admin-mode...

Comment: The same issue even for me. I solved deleting manually a folder as described [here](https://github.com/MiKTeX/miktex-packaging/issues/137).