# Error when compiling code with \includemedia and \media9 only on a specific machine

Tags: beamer, media9

I use the code below

```
\includemedia[
        label=freezing,
        width=0.9\linewidth, height=0.675\linewidth,
        addresource=freezingVideo.mp4,
        transparent,
        activate=pageopen,
        passcontext,  %show VPlayer's right-click menu
        flashvars={
            source=freezingVideo.mp4
            &loop=true
        }
    ]{}{VPlayer.swf}
```

to insert a video in a frame with the package `media9` in `beamer`. This code compiles (XeLateX) without errors on a machine (Windows 7 with MiKTeX) and produces correctly the embedded video. However the same code on a different machine with the eaxct same configuration (Windows 7, XeLateX, MiKTeX) gives me the following error:

```
Argument of \prg_map_break:Nn has an extra }. \end{frame}
```

I updated MiKTeX on the machine which gives error and this does not change the problem. There are a bunch of differences between the log files obtained in the two machines (you can find them [here](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1ABx5ZmRx7uwDZbBn495yYerTFD9NLHgj) named as GOOD and BAD, respectively for the machine not giving any error and the one failing to compile properly) all of which seem to derive from th fact that miktex was recently updated on the BAD machine. I have no idea where this does come from.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Shouldn't there be a `,` after `source=freezingVideo.mp4`?

Comment: uhm I do not think so since I use the `&` to add the looping option. Anyway this code works perfectly with one machine.

Comment: Add `\listfiles` at the top of the source, build again on both machines, compare the `*.log` files. (Look for section `File List` and compare package versions/dates.)

Comment: @AlexG there are a bunch of differences between the log files all of which seem to depend from the fact that miktex was recently updated on the machine failing to compile. But I am unable to understand where the problem comes from. The logs are attached now.

Comment: Would you please extend the code above to a minimal compilable example ([MWE](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3225)), starting with `\documentclass{beamer}` and ending with `\end{document}`?

Comment: I don't know if related, but same day ago I've had problem after update. [https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/517339/miktex-re-downloading-iftex](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/517339/miktex-re-downloading-iftex)